# Python : BeautifulSoup - Find the elements (meta) that doesnt contain specific tag (itemprop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How do i find the elements (`meta`) that doesn't contain specific attribute (`itemprop`)

**HTML:**

> <html><body><meta content="Hello data world" /><meta content="$3500" itemprop="price" /><meta content="9876543210" itemprop="telephone" /><meta content="DOLLAR" itemprop="unitCode"/></body></html>

**Beautifulsoup selection :**

> soup.select('meta')

**Output** :

> [<meta content="Hello data world"/>, <meta content="$3500" itemprop="price"/>, <meta content="9876543210" itemprop="telephone"/>, <meta content="DOLLAR" itemprop="unitCode"/>]

**Required output** :

> [<meta content="Hello data world"/>]

Answer (score 0):

Just filter with `attr.get("itemprop") is None`:

```py
soup = [
    m for m
    in BeautifulSoup(sampel_html, "html.parser").select("meta")
    if m.get("itemprop") is None
]
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
[<meta content="Hello data world"/>]
```

Or, how about using `select_one()`?

For example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sampel_html = """<html><body><meta content="Hello data world" /><meta content="$3500" itemprop="price" /><meta content="9876543210" itemprop="telephone" /><meta content="DOLLAR" itemprop="unitCode"/></body></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sampel_html, "html.parser").select_one("meta")
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<meta content="Hello data world"/>
```

And then:

```
print(soup["content"])
```

To get:

```
Hello data world
```